# How can I center my menu and drop menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well I built a new menu and drop menu and I would like you to help me center it because I can't succeed doing it.

CODE:

```css
.drop_menu {
 background:#005555;
 padding:0;
 margin:15px 0;
 list-style-type:none;
 height:30px;
 width: 100%;
}

.drop_menu li 
{ 
    float:right;  
}

.drop_menu li a 
{
 padding:9px 20px;
 display:block;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 font:12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}

.drop_menu ul 
{
 position:absolute;
 right:-9999px;
 top:-9999px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
.drop_menu li:hover 
{ 
    height: 100%;
    position:relative; 
    background:#5FD367; 
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul 
{
 right:0px;
 top:30px;
 background:#5FD367;
 padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
 padding:5px;
 display:block;
 width:168px;
 text-indent:15px;
 background-color:#5FD367;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover 
{ 
    background:#005555;
}
```

```html
    <body dir="rtl">
        <div class="drop">
            <ul class = "drop_menu">
                <li ><a href="Default.aspx">דף הבית</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Registration.aspx">הרשמה</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Login.aspx">התחברות</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Default.aspx">אודות</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Default.aspx">צור קשר</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Default.aspx">קישורים נוספים</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Gallery.aspx">תיק עבודות</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">תת תפריט</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">תת תפריט</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

Please help me and if the solution isn't simple it will great if you will explain it to me because I am new and learning within school so we are not focusing the design things.. Thank you guys :)

Comment: What do you want to center?

Comment: All the menu, I mean that all the texts will be in the center of the bar.

Like this: http://prntscr.com/6baoo8, in the center but with my codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have float:right in your li so, they will go to the right of your page, remove it, and use `display:inline-block` instead.
2. add a `text-align:center;` to your .drop-menu

When you use float:right, you data will go to be like a floating object, and its width will be about your content. if you remove it, you need to specify a width, so you can have inline-block to tell your tag to have its width base on its content.

```css
.drop_menu {
 background:#005555;
 padding:0;
 margin:15px 0;
 list-style-type:none;
 height:30px;
 text-align:center;
}

.drop_menu li 
{ 
    display:inline-block;
}

.drop_menu li a 
{
 padding:9px 20px;
 display:block;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 font:12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}

.drop_menu ul 
{
 position:absolute;
 right:-9999px;
 top:-9999px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
.drop_menu li:hover 
{ 
    height: 100%;
    position:relative; 
    background:#5FD367;         
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul 
{
 right:0px;
 top:30px;
 background:#5FD367;
 padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
 padding:5px;
 display:block;
 width:168px;
 text-indent:15px;
 background-color:#5FD367;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover 
{ 
    background:#005555;
}
```

```html
    <body dir="rtl">
        <div class="drop">
            <ul class = "drop_menu">
                <li ><a href="Default.aspx">דף הבית</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Registration.aspx">הרשמה</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Login.aspx">התחברות</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Default.aspx">אודות</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Default.aspx">צור קשר</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Default.aspx">קישורים נוספים</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Gallery.aspx">תיק עבודות</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">תת תפריט</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">תת תפריט</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the menu  inline block and center it with text-align.

```css
.drop {
 text-align:center;
 background:#005555;
}

.drop_menu {
 background:#005555;
 padding:0;
 margin:15px 0;
 list-style-type:none;
 height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
 
}

.drop_menu li 
{ 
    float:right;  
}

.drop_menu li a 
{
 padding:9px 20px;
 display:block;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 font:12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}

.drop_menu ul 
{
 position:absolute;
 right:-9999px;
 top:-9999px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
.drop_menu li:hover 
{ 
    height: 100%;
    position:relative; 
    background:#5FD367; 
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul 
{
 right:0px;
 top:30px;
 background:#5FD367;
 padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
 padding:5px;
 display:block;
 width:168px;
 text-indent:15px;
 background-color:#5FD367;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover 
{ 
    background:#005555;
}
```

```html
    <body dir="rtl">
        <div class="drop">
            <ul class = "drop_menu">
                <li ><a href="Default.aspx">דף הבית</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Registration.aspx">הרשמה</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Login.aspx">התחברות</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Default.aspx">אודות</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Default.aspx">צור קשר</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="Default.aspx">קישורים נוספים</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Gallery.aspx">תיק עבודות</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">תת תפריט</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">תת תפריט</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But then it won't be 100% width which I do want it, and don't put the text-align in the body because I don't want everything to be in center. Look at the new code, I will add the width: 100% and it won't work right.

Comment: Oh..well instead of `body` put it on the `drop` div. Answer updated

Comment: Someone else helped me already but still a good solution, thank you very much :D